# ASP.net web form - post data to a controller in an MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest

This may be a stupid question, but anyway... I have an MVC site and a legacy ASP.net web forms site.  I have a controller action on my MVC site that I would like to (programatically) POST to from my web forms site.

I can find lots of information describing RESTful services etc., but I can't seem to find a resource that explains how to do this bit - anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

In MVC, there is nothing special about the `FORM` on the page (unlike WebForms).

Just create a normal HTML `FORM` (without `runat="server"`).  Set the `action` to point to your controller action.  Set the `method` to `POST`.

That's it.  In your controller action, you can access the `FormCollection` directly, or you can attempt to use parameter/model binding.

Comment: Indeed - I'd like to be able to do this programatically (i.e. I have an existing webform, and when that POSTs back in my web forms site, I'd like to add in an extra call to my MVC site).

Comment: Ah, in that case - you need to submit the POST in your event handler.  For simple sets of data, take a look at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues().

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920035/net-fail-to-post-form-by-httpwebresponse/1920562#1920562) demonstrates how to post data to web server with [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).
You just need to compose your own data to be posted, and change the url that the data will be posted to. It's the url of your controller in your case.